# Re-order axis in Plotly graph

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, plotly, axis

I have data of ~3 years organised by month and year. I want to plot this data as a bar chart by month and year, with the month as the x-axis and the year as a trace. The problem is that the data starts in September 2018, so the first month to be plotted is September, but I want it to be January. I've tried to do that but then the years are in decreasing order, which I don't want either.
Here is a code example.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({})
numdays = 1000
base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(numdays)]
price = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(numdays)]
df['price'] = price
df.index = date_list
df = df.resample('MS').sum()
df['month'] = df.index.month_name()
df['month number'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year
year_list = df['year'].unique().tolist()
fig = go.Figure()

for year in year_list:
    df_aux = df[df.year==year]
    df_aux = df_aux.sort_values(by=['month number'])
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_aux.month, y=df_aux['price'], \
                          name=year))

fig.show()
```

This is what I get, but it starts in September and I want it to be January:

[image: This is what I get, but it starts in September and I want it to be January]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Using this reference for [categorical axes from plotly](https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/#automatically-sorting-categories-by-name-or-total-value), I was able to use the `categoryorder` and set the `catergoryarray`, which allows you to set the list of the order that you want to use for your axis.

From the documentation/reference:

> Whether using Plotly Express or not, categories can be sorted alphabetically or by value using the categoryorder attribute:

and also:

> This example shows how to control category order when using
> plotly.graph_objects by defining categoryorder to "array" to derive
> the ordering from the attribute categoryarray.

The line of code that I added was:

```
fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='array', categoryarray= ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'])
```

and this gave an output which looked like this:

[image]

The complete code:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({})
numdays = 1000
base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(numdays)]
price = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(numdays)]
df['price'] = price
df.index = date_list
df = df.resample('MS').sum()
df['month'] = df.index.month_name()
df['month number'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year
year_list = df['year'].unique().tolist()

fig = go.Figure()

for year in year_list:
    df_aux = df[df.year==year]
    df_aux = df_aux.sort_values(by=['month number'])
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_aux.month, y=df_aux['price'], \
                          name=year))

fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='array', categoryarray= ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'])

fig.show()
```

Comment: It also works using `plotly.express` such as `import plotly.express as px` and using `px.bar`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define category_orders for month like this:

```
    import datetime
    import pandas as pd
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    import random

    df = pd.DataFrame({})
    numdays = 1000
    base = datetime.datetime.today()
    date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(numdays)]
    price = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(numdays)]
    df['price'] = price
    df.index = date_list
    df = df.resample('MS').sum()
    df['month'] = df.index.month_name()
    df['year'] = df.index.year
    df['year'] = pd.Categorical(df['year'])
    fig = px.bar(df,x='month', y='price',
                 category_orders={'month':['January', 'February', 'March',
                                        'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 
                                        'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']},
                color='year',barmode="group")

    fig.show()
```

[image]