# How to custom order the x axis category orders in plotly express subplots

Tags: python, visualization, plotly-express

Below shown is the data to plot the bar chart in plotly express subplots

[image]

Below is the syntax is used to create the bar chart in plotly express subplots by using **category_orders to customize the order of the x axis's**.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


# Male Trace
trace1  = go.Bar(
                        x = df[df['Gender']=='Male']['Job_Satisfaction'],
                        y = df[df['Gender']=='Male']['count'],
                        name = 'Male',
                        text = ['{}, {:.0%}'.format(v, p/100) for v,p in zip( df[df['Gender']=='Male']['count'],  df[df['Gender']=='Male']['%'])],
                        textposition = 'inside',
                        marker_color = ['#06266B']*len(df['Job_Satisfaction']),
                        category_orders ={'Job_Satisfaction':['Low','Medium','High','Very High']},
                       )

# Female Trace
trace2  = go.Bar(
                        x = df[df['Gender']=='Female']['Job_Satisfaction'],
                        y = df[df['Gender']=='Female']['count'],
                        name = 'Female',
                        text = ['{}, {:.0%}'.format(v, p/100) for v,p in zip( df[df['Gender']=='Female']['count'],  df[df['Gender']=='Female']['%'])],
                        textposition = 'inside',
                        marker_color = ['#8F0396']*len(df['Job_Satisfaction']),
                        category_orders  ={'Job_Satisfaction':['Low','Medium','High','Very High']},
                       )


fig.append_trace(trace1,1,2)
fig.append_trace(trace2,1,2)

fig.show()
```

and I do get the below error message

[image]

How do I get a bar chart by customizing the orders in plotly express subplots from Job_Satisfaction column where the order of the x axis's should be 'Low','Medium','High','Very High'. And the Bar Chart should look shown below

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-order axis in Plotly graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68061197/re-order-axis-in-plotly-graph)

Comment: As per the suggested duplicate, add: `fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='array', categoryarray= ['Low','Medium','High','Very High'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To order categorical entries, you can update the dataframe by using `pd.Categorical()` and sorting the data you want to plot instead to doing it in the plot. You can comment out the two lines with `category_orders ={..}` and ad these two lines before plotting.

```
df['Job_Satisfaction'] = pd.Categorical(df['Job_Satisfaction'], ["Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High"])
df.sort_values(['Job_Satisfaction'], inplace=True)
```

This will give the plot as below. I used the same data as what was in the previous example.

[image]